# mongoose find if array of references of a document contains an IdObject

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

im using **nodejs** express and **mongodb**
this is part of my schema:

```
var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
     friends: [{
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "User",
            unique: true
        }],
        sentRequests: [{
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "User",
            unique: true
        }],
        receivedRequests: [{
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "User",
            unique: true
        }]
    }
var User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

i want to query if a user with a specefic **id is in any array ** (friends, sentRequests or receivedRequests) **of another user** :
i used this approach but **I have to do this for 3 arrays and it's slow**:

```
UserSchema.statics.relStatus = function(User1ID, User2ID) {
    var User = this;
    User.find({
        _id: User1ID,
        friends: {
            _id: User2ID
        }
    }).then((err, res) => {
        if (res) {
            return ' they are friends';
        }
    });
```

Comment: Did ou try indexing the 3 fields ? It could enhance the queries speed.

Comment: thas not what im looking for, im looking for a proper query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with following aggregation query (if you are using mongo 3.4 or higher):

```
User.aggregate([
{ $match: { _id: User1ID } },
{
    $facet: {
        friends: [{ $match: { friends: User2ID } }],
        sentRequests: [{ $match: { sentRequests: User2ID } }],
        receivedRequests: [{ $match: { receivedRequests: User2ID } }]
    }
},
{
    $project: {
        relationship: {
           $switch: {
              branches: [
                 { case: { $anyElementTrue: [ "$friends" ] }, then: "friends" },
                 { case: { $anyElementTrue: [ "$sentRequests" ] }, then: "sentRequests" },
                 { case: { $anyElementTrue: [ "$receivedRequests" ] }, then: "receivedRequests" },
              ],
             default: false
           }
        }
    }
}
])
```

Result will be object in following format `{relationship: "<RELATIONSHIP_TYPE>"}`
or `{relationship: false}` if they have no relationship.
First stage of the aggregation pipeline will match single document by `_id` (which is indexed by default), so you shouldnt have any performance issues.

Answer (score -1):

In order to query for multiple field you can user **'$or'**.

```
User.find({
    _id: User1ID,
    {
        $or: [
            {friends: $in:[User2ID]},
            {sentRequests: $in:[User2ID]},
            {receivedRequests: $in:[User2ID]}
        ]
    }
}).then((err, res) => {
    if (res) {
        return ' they are friends';
    }
});
```

$or will return a user which have User2ID in either 'friends' or 'sentRequests' or 'receivedRequests'.

Read more about ['$or'](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/index.html) and ['$in'](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/index.html)

Hope this helps.

Comment: actually, i tried this but this approach doesn't inform which array really contained that user

Comment: You have to check it manually. This approach will give you quick response and you don't have to Query for 3 times

Comment: @tahalahij what you are trying to achieve that cannot be achieve by query. This query will return you object that have _id of User1ID and User2ID in one of this fields(i.e. friends, sentRequests or receivedRequests), after getting query result you have to do it manually which field have User2ID. Or you can stick to your approach(i.e. querying 3 times).

Comment: the query using $or will return a user which have User2ID in either of arrays , how can i extract from the  returned user that which array contained User2ID  ?